# Eigenvalues of Nonsquare Operator Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{array}{l}{\text { Let } V \text { be the vector space over } \mathbb{C} \text { of all complex polynomials of degree }} \\ {\text { at most } 10 . \text { Let } D: V \rightarrow V \text { be the differentiation operator, so } D f(x)=f^{\prime}(x) . \text { Find }} \\ {\text { all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the operator } e^{D} \text { on } V .}\end{array}

The matrix I used in this problem to represent $D$ was a 10 by 10 matrix with the diagonal being 0's and one above the diagonal being 1,2,...,9. But I am not sure where to go from there.

Thank you.

Comment: If the matrix of $e^D$ is triangular you know the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $D$ with eigenvector $v$ if and only if $e^{\lambda t}$ is an eigenvalue of $e^{tD}$ with eigenvector $v$. You can prove this by the fact that every matrix can be decomposed with the Jordan decomposition and by considering the matrix exponential of a Jordan block.

More specifically, if $D = PJP^{-1}$, then $e^{tD} = Pe^{tJ}P^{-1}$. The matrix exponential of $e^{tJ}$ is easy to get a general formula for because each Jordan block $J_j$ is a nilpotent matrix plus a scalar multiple of the identity, ie $J_j = \lambda_j I + N$, and since they commute, 
$$e^{tJ_j} = e^{\lambda_j tI}e^{tN} = e^{\lambda_j t}e^{tN}.$$
$N$ is nilpotent, so evaluating the power series for $e^{Nt}$ is simple. Putting the exponential of all the Jordan blocks into a block diagonal matrix then gives $e^{tJ}$. From that result you will easily see why the first statement is true.

Therefore for this problem you need to find all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of your matrix representation of $D$ and then apply the theorem.